# Diferença entre CAST e CONVERT em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Para resolver um problema acabei por me cruzar com duas soluções onde numa era utilizada a função [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) para converter um número em texto, noutra era utilizada a função [`CONVERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) para o mesmo efeito.

**As duas funções, o mesmo efeito prático:**

```
SELECT (CAST(10 AS DECIMAL)) + 10; # resulta em: 20

SELECT (CONVERT(10,DECIMAL)) + 10; # resulta em: 20
```

**Um exemplo simples onde o `CAST()` e o `CONVERT()` se tornam úteis:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(10, 10); # resulta em: 31303130
```

Mas se queremos juntar os dois valores como se se tratassem de texto:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(10 AS CHAR), 10);  # resulta em: 1010

SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(10,CHAR), 10);  # resulta em: 1010
```

Ficou no entanto a duvida de porque é que temos duas funções que fazem exatamente o mesmo.

## Pergunta

Em MySQL qual a diferença entre as funções `CAST()` e `CONVERT()` ?

Answer (score 11):

Considerando os exemplos que você citou, **não há diferença além da sintaxe**. As duas funções inclusive são descritas na [mesma página na documentação do MySql](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/cast-functions.html).

A explicação da documentação para a existência de ambas é que **CONVERT** é especificada pelo padrão [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710252(v=vs.85).aspx) enquanto **CAST** é especificada pelo padrão [ANSI SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt). Não há indícios de diferenças de performance ou coisas do gênero.

Quando usado com uma sintaxe diferente, **CONVERT** pode converter um *character set* em outro (`CONVERT... USING...`). O comando `CAST` não tem esta opção.

### Refletindo:

O que eu acho interessante é que uma engine de banco de dados não precisa suportar a sintaxe ODBC para poder ser acessada via ODBC.

Veja por exemplo a [documentação ODBC para a própria função CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715381(v=vs.85).aspx). Ela mostra o seguinte exemplo:

Se uma aplicação especifica o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE {fn CONVERT(EMPNO,SQL_CHAR)} LIKE '1%'
```

Um driver Oracle o traduz para:

```
SELECT EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE to_char(EMPNO) LIKE '1%'
```

Ora, se o driver precisa traduzir o comando, o CONVERT não precisaria ser suportado pela engine do MySql; apenas as implementações de Driver ODBC para MySql são obrigadas a lidar com esta função.

Minha conclusão para a engine do MySql suportar ambas as funções é que o `CAST` fica limitado ao padrão ANSI SQL, enquanto o `CONVERT` pode assumir variações para o benefício do desenvolvedor MySql. Por enquanto, sua única variação parece ser a sintaxe `USING` para definir a conversão de um *character set* em outro (ainda que esta sintaxe esteja prevista no obscuro SQL-99).

Como suporte a esta conclusão, podemos estudar também a função CONVERT do MS SQL Server e do Oracle. Em [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), o CONVERT pode receber um terceiro parâmetro para especificar um formato ou estilo de data, além de poder ser usado com o mesmo objetivo do CAST. E no [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm) o CONVERT serve exclusivamente para converter um *character set* em outro (separando os parâmetros por vírgula sem a palavra *using* na sintaxe.

Ou seja, além do comum e *multicompatível* **CAST**, os SGBDs suportam ainda variações do **CONVERT** para agraciar seus desenvolvedores exclusivos.