# Qual a diferença entre Cast e Convert?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tsql, cast

Em um livro de Transact-SQL(Série Ramalho) é dito:

## CAST E CONVERT

> Converte implicitamente uma expressão de tipos de dados para outro.
> CAST é um sinônimo de CONVERT.

O que quer dizer com CAST é um sinônimo de CONVERT? Qual a orientação de uso de um e outro? Existe uma implicação de desempenho entre ambos?

Comment: @Henrique será que é a mesma coisa?

Comment: [Link útil](https://diariodba.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/convertendo-dados-cast-ou-convert/)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença entre CAST e CONVERT em MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39368/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-cast-e-convert-em-mysql)

Comment: Marconi e @IvanFerrer Os fins são os mesmos. **Eu acredio** que os meios sejam diferentes e, mesmo que seja tudo igual, acho importante que você mantenha a pergunta, Marconi. Mesmo que ela seja fechada. Aí, quando alguém for procurar isso sobre SQL Server vai cair aqui e vai ver que a resposta se encontra na outra pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi: CONVERT possui mais opções do que CAST. // Deve-se ter cuidado no uso da função CAST, pois em alguns casos ela utiliza configurações da sessão para decidir como será a conversão. Já na função CONVERT se define a regra de conversão.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CONVERT` é uma função específica do `SQL Server` e `CAST` é padrão `ANSI`.

Existe uma tabela de conversão que pode ser utilizada para decidir se deve ou não utilizar alguma função de conversão para cada caso:

[image: Tabela de conversão]

Seguindo as informações da tabela, caso seja necessário realizar uma conversão de `varchar` para `date` podemos fazer implicitamente:

```
DECLARE @data DATE = '2017-06-21';
```

Ou para converter um `datetime` para `timestamp` deve-se fazer explicitamente:

```
DECLARE @data DATETIME = getdate();
DECLARE @hora TIMESTAMP = CAST(@data AS TIMESTAMP);
```

Quanto a performance, não existe uma regra. Para cada tipo há uma variação mínima entre os dois usos.

---

Referências:

- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql%20%22CAST%20and%20CONVERT%20(Transact-SQL))
- [T-SQL Cast versus Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707433/3388148)

Comment: Conversão explicita é o CONVERT e o implícito é o CAST? não saquei a imagem.

Comment: A imagem é o que você pode utilizar, ou não, sem usar nenhuma função. Não serve pra diferenciar um do outro. É só uma curiosidade

Comment: Não entendi a tabela também @Sorack! Poderia explicar?

Comment: @Marconi a tabela de conversão indica se você pode fazer a atribuição diretamente ou se tem que usar alguma função, por exemplo `declare @data date = '2017-06-21'`

Comment: @Sorack tem como adicionar esses tipos de conversões na resposta?Acho que a tabela ficou bem intuitiva, mas dá pra melhorar um pouco mais a resposta =D

Comment: @Marconi achei a seguinte [explicação](http://www.guj.com.br/t/casting-explicito-implicito/40844/3)

Comment: @Marconi adicionado

Answer (score 1):

As duas possuem a mesma finalidade.
A única diferença é que a CAST é mais alinhada ao padrão ISO, enquanto CONVERT é mais alinhada ao T-SQL.

Podem ser usadas desta forma:

```
SELECT 9.5 AS Original, CAST(9.5 AS int) AS int, 
    CAST(9.5 AS decimal(6,4)) AS decimal;

SELECT 9.5 AS Original, CONVERT(int, 9.5) AS int, 
    CONVERT(decimal(6,4), 9.5) AS decimal;
```

Referência:
[CAST & CONVERT (TRANSACT SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

As duas funções (CAST e CONVERT) possuem a mesma finalidade, portanto fazem a mesma coisa, que é a conversão do tipo de dados de uma expressão. Não há muita diferença entre as duas funções, como já dito anteriormente, a função CAST é padrão ISO e a CONVERT é T-SQL. A diferença mais relevante que vejo entre as duas funções é que, na função CONVERT, para a conversão de tipos de dados DATETIME, há um terceiro parâmetro para "escolher" o padrão de data/hora desejado, conforme tabela disponibilizada no site da Microsoft, que a função CAST não dá suporte. Ao meu ver essa é uma funcionalidade interessante, principalmente quando tratamos de instruções entre sistemas e bancos de dados diferentes, onde cada um armazena a data em um formato diferente. Dessa forma, utilizando a função CONVERT do SQL Server, você pode tirar mais vantagem. Agora, em termos de performance, não há diferença relevante para utilizar uma ao invés de outra.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017